# QApplication::aboutToQuit() not emitted when no windows is visible

Tags: windows, qt

I have a small Windows 7 application with a system tray icon (QSystemTrayIcon). Upon minimizing the window is hidden with `hide()` so that it is visible in the tray only, not in the task bar.

The application needs to perform some cleanup when quitting. This is managed by a AppMgr QObject which does the cleanup when destroyed.

The AppMgr is connected to aboutToQuit for that purpose:

```
AppMgr * appMgr = new AppMgr (&qApplication);
qApp.connect(&qApp, &QApplication::aboutToQuit, appMgr , &AppMgr::deleteLater);
```

When closing the session, this works well if the window is visible, but not if it is hidden : no clean-up is not performed. Does Windows signal tell the application to close only if a window is visible, or is this a Qt bug?

Thanks

Comment: How exactly do you exit your application if the window is hidden?

Comment: By logging off the desktop session. If the window is visible the QApplication emits an aboutToQuit signal as documented. If the window is hidden, no signal is emitted.

Comment: For reference, here is a bug reported on this in Qt's issue system: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-54316